# Uploading file(s) to webserver in silverlight (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, upload

Alright, so i have a silverlight application,

it opens a filedialog, gets the selected file, transfers it to asp.net which saves it to the server, but i want to know how to implement a progress bar for it. for big files, and multiple file uploads, i will need to know the progress of the file upload to the server, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably save yourself a lot of time and heartache by just integrating this [Silverlight File Upload](http://silverlightfileupld.codeplex.com/) codeplex project into your app.

You can't actual get good progress information from the standard `WebRequest` or `WebClient` components.  Not only do they not send any of the Request stream until your code has finished writing to it (a decision I can't begin to understand), it doesn't provide any progress events once it starts sending it.  For reasons I can't begin to fathom you can get progress events when sending a string, go figure.

I can only guess that these limitations arise from Silverlight needing to operate in multiple browsers and therefore the interface to the Browser HTTP transport is kept as basic as possible.